# The Poem's in the Wires

Tags: cipher, poetry

Here's one I thought folks here might appreciate. It'll require a combination of codebreaking (or code*finding*) and a tiny dab of cryptic mindset.

What poem is written below?
For bonus points, provide the literal translation of what's written below.

While you theoretically don't need a computer for this, I'll be shocked if anyone does solve this without one. Especially if you don't have an internet connection...

```
emzwo agzan fjifj emzwo agzan fjifj
emzwo agzan fjifj ijvzo sadsg
agjou eshiy 0978 ietob cetne muuol ovcma hyupv
ehuph ovcma fuarp arkla agibh
axesu ehgej ovcma emusp eocgy myjpa
ezbor 0978 ietob cetne
muuol ovcma hyupv
```

Hint #1:

> Strictly speaking, this isn't a cipher. Not every code is designed to hide what's being said.

Hint #2 (Cryptic):

> Bugs Bunny might have found this (slightly) easier than you.

Comment: Can you add a hint?

Comment: @WOWOW Bit early for a hint! It's only been live 2 hours and someone might fancy a crack at it in its current form :)

Comment: Like you, as I have seen in your answers to other questions :P

Comment: Heh heh. I'll give it a hint tomorrow at work, just going to bed now. There's some subtle but very cryptic hints already in the title and description, but they're extremely vague. Good luck!

Comment: When will you add it?

Comment: Five minutes tops!

Comment: First two hints are up. Decided to provide a secondary hint as it's pretty dang cryptic but might nudge someone who's already close.

Comment: I think I am seeing substitution...

Comment: Who is Bugs Bunny?

Comment: You might want to google it, though if you don't know him, it might not be very helpful...

Comment: I know *what* this is, but fifteen minutes of googling isn't finding me the correct book. I have found a website with scans of roughly a hundred different books and I don't care to try each one.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I'll give you a bonus clue; one of the hints I've provided should nudge you towards the right book...

Comment: I had more success finding the poem than the book.

Comment: Interesting! You're welcome to post an answer, I'd love to see what method you used. I'd give green checkmark preference to someone who gives a complete solve, but if no such answer is forthcoming you'd get it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Plaintext

> Half a league, half a league,
> Half a league onward,
> All in the valley of Death
>    Rode the six hundred.
> “Forward, the Light Brigade!
> Charge for the guns!” he said.
> Into the valley of Death
>    Rode the six hundred.
>
>  The Charge of the Light Brigade, by Alfred, Lord Tennyson

## Encryption

> As the title "The Poem's in the Wires" implies, this is a commercial telegraph code. Unlike military codes, commercial codes were not kept secret and were used by the public to reduce the cost of sending telegrams by making them shorter. [Here is the website I found](https://www.jmcvey.net/cable/scans.htm) that lists hundreds of commercial codes. This poem was written in 1854 during the heyday of the Morse telegraph, so it is not impossible that it would have been sent by wire, though maybe not with this particular codebook.

> This is a one-part code. This means the codebook only contains the code once, with both plain words and code words in alphabetical order. This implies that after breaking an encoded message, recovering the plain equivalents for several code words, and putting the code words in alphabetical order, then the plain equivalents will also be in alphabetical order. This can be exploited by the codebreaker to eliminate possibilities for the remaining codewords after one or more codewords are known or assumed. Because of this weakness, most military codes were eventually replaced with two-part codes, where there is no alphabetical order and the book must reproduce the code in both encoding (organized by plaintext) and decoding (organized by codeword) formats.

> Here is the coded text written above the plaintext, followed by the recovered code words which show their plain equivalents in alphabetical order. I am uncertain about one codeword, and another is a complete mystery.

> ```
> emzwo agzan fjifj   emzwo agzan fjifj
> Half  a     league, half  a     league,
>
> emzwo agzan fjifj  ijvzo    sadsg
> Half  a     league on-      ward,
>
> agjou eshiy 0978       ietob cetne muuol ovcma hyupv
> All   in    the valley of    Death Rode  the   six hundred.
>
> ehuph     ovcma   fuarp arkla    agibh axesu  ehgej ovcma emusp  eocgy myjpa
> “Forward, the     Light Brigade!  <?>  Charge for   the   guns!” he    said.
>
> ezbor 0978        ietob  cetne muuol ovcma   hyupv
> Into  the  valley of     Death Rode  the     six hundred.
>
>
> 0978  - the valley
> agibh - ???
> agjou - all
> agzan - a
> arkla - brigade
> axesu - charge
> cetne - death
> ehgej - for
> ehuph - forward
> emusp - guns
> emzwo - half
> eocgy - he
> eshiy - in
> ezbor - into
> fjifj - league
> fuarp - light
> hyupv - 600?
> ietob - of
> ijvzo - on
> muuol - rode
> myjpa - said
> ovcma - the
> sadsg - ward
> ```

## What did I Google to find the poem?

> poem first few words repeat three times

Comment: Not bad! So, you have the poem correct, but strictly speaking, your **plaintext is wrong**, in two places. Hence why you've got a codeword you couldn't translate. If we don't have a full translation/solve by the end of the day you'll win :)

Comment: What does this have to do with Bugs Bunny?

Comment: The Bugs Bunny clue hints towards the correct codebook. As @codewarrior0 correctly stated, there were many such telegraph codebooks. Only one is the precisely correct one that leads to the fully plaintext.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, decoding a coded message with the codebook in hand is **not codebreaking**. :P

Comment: Hence why the question says **"(or codefinding)"** :P - By the way, if you're still curious, @codewarrior0, the codebook you're looking for isn't actually in the list you've provided. It is somewhere more public though.

Comment: I'm just going to guess that it's the "Acme" code.

Comment: As you're so close and you've got most of it anyway, I'll let you know that the only things you need to look up at this stage are 0978, muuol, arkla, agibh, sadsg and possibly hyupv :)

Comment: The only one I was actually curious about is 0978, which is the name of a steamship.

Comment: Stick the name in google translate :P